# Convert html String to org.w3c.dom.Document in Java

Tags: java

To convert from HTML String to

> org.w3c.dom.Document

I'm using

> jtidy-r938.jar

here is my code:

```
public static Document getDoc(String html) {
        Tidy tidy = new Tidy();
        tidy.setInputEncoding("UTF-8");
        tidy.setOutputEncoding("UTF-8");
        tidy.setWraplen(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        // tidy.setPrintBodyOnly(true);
        tidy.setXmlOut(false);
        tidy.setShowErrors(0);
        tidy.setShowWarnings(false);
        // tidy.setForceOutput(true);
        tidy.setQuiet(true);
        Writer out = new StringWriter();
        PrintWriter dummyOut = new PrintWriter(out);
        tidy.setErrout(dummyOut);
        tidy.setSmartIndent(true);
        ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(html.getBytes());
        Document doc = tidy.parseDOM(inputStream, null);
        return doc;
    }
```

But sometime the library work incorrectly, some tag is lost.

Please tell a good open library to do this task.

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't tell why sometimes the library doesn't give the good result.
Nevertheless, i am working very regularly with html files where I must extract data from and the main problem encountered is that fact that some tags are not valid because not closed for example. 
The best solution i found to resolve is the api htmlcleaner ([htmlCleaner Website](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/index.php)).

It allows you to make your html file well formed.
Then, to transform it in document w3c or another strict format file is easier.

With HtmlCleaner, you could do such as :

```
HtmlCleaner cleaner = new HtmlCleaner();
TagNode node = cleaner.clean(html);
DomSerializer ser = new DomSerializer(cleaner.getProperties());
Document myW3cDoc = ser.createDOM(node);
```

I refer DomSerializer from htmlcleaner.

Comment: Hi, I tried HtmlCleaner. It convert to Document well but I can using xpath to get Node in this case. Please tell me how to do it. In jTidy i use this code: public static Node getNodeViaXpath(Node doc, String xpath) throws XPathExpressionException{
  XPathFactory xPathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
  XPath xPath = xPathFactory.newXPath();
  String expression = xpath;
  XPathExpression xPathExpression = xPath.compile(expression);
  Object result = xPathExpression.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODE);
  Node node = (Node) result;
  return node;
 }

Comment: Hi, I would help you but could you drive me  further by explaining me which is the problem that you have encountered with the code you posted ?

Comment: Here is a example website http://bongdaso.com/Indonesia-Philippines-2015_06_09-_Fix_43073.aspx?LeagueID=42&SeasonID=237&Data=Odds#.  I want to get the tag <a href="Indonesia-Philippines-2015_06_09-_Fix_43073.aspx.aspx?LeagueID=42&amp;SeasonID=237&amp;Data=odds"><h4>Tỷ lệ cược</h4></a>  via xpath. The tag is lost if I user jTidy. How can I get the tag via xpath by HTMLCleaner